# Is there a function to 'resize' the page like opening and closing the developer console does?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am currently working with the Autodesk Forge Viewer and have implemented a method to allow two viewer panels to be open simultaneously. You can position the second panel by dragging it to either the top, right, or bottom, similar to the drag-and-drop functionality in VS Code.

But for instance, when I open a second panel to the right of the main panel, then close it, and reopen it on top of the main panel, the viewer only fills a fraction its designated area. It just doesn't resize properly. However, I have noticed that if I open and close the developer console, it resizes correctly.

To note is, that the viewer panels are inside a div-box which resizes properly.

My question is, is there a JavaScript method that I can implement to automatically resize the elements every time a panel is opened or closed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems to me that it could be a CSS styling issue. Have you tried resizing the divs in your main CSS file? You can give this a try.